# Iteration in python

Tags: python

Hi I would like create some code which will print a box that looks like this

```
 + -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
 |    |    |    |    |    |
 + -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
```

The code should use a loop to print a row of boxes using for i in range(5)(There should be no use of IF statement to solve this problem) by using one box only as shown below

```
+ -- +
|    |
+ -- +
```

I have attempted to use the code below but not producing the output required. Please help

```
for i in range(5):
    print("+--+\n|  |\n+--+", end=" ")
```

Comment: You need to rethink your approach. You clearly can't just `print` a single box five times--not only will you repeat "walls" that way, but if each box contains newlines, there's no way to "stack" them horizontally. You'll need to do the loop *first*, create the three lines you need to print, and then print them out once they're complete.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question. Why the restriction on using that specific loop construct?

Comment: What is the desired behavior for printBoxes(0)? A vertical line, or no drawing at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the way your teacher *wants* you to solve this is by using the `for` loop to build up the three lines, box by box, and then print all three lines. Or, noticing that the top and bottom are the same, just use the same line for each:

```
edge, middle = '+', '|'
for i in range(5):
    edge += ' -- +'
    middle += '    |'
print(edge)
print(middle)
print(edge)
```

However, the answers using the `*` string repetition operator and/or the `join` method are much more Pythonic. If you can explain to your teacher how they work, and why they're better, and if your teacher isn't overly rigid (or stupid), that might be worth doing. Even if you don't want to try that, learning why they're better on your own may be worth doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a combination of using the `*` operator to make a string of characters, and `join` to add delimiters between those characters.

```
def printBoxes(boxes):
    edges = ' -- '.join('+' * (boxes+1))
    middle = '    '.join('|' * (boxes+1))
    print(edges)
    print(middle)
    print(edges)
```

Testing

```
>>> printBoxes(3)
+ -- + -- + -- +
|    |    |    |
+ -- + -- + -- +

>>> printBoxes(5)
+ -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
|    |    |    |    |    |
+ -- + -- + -- + -- + -- +
```

Comment: Nitpick-- there are no cubes here. ;-)

Comment: :P Fair enough, renamed

Comment: The homework required you to use a loop, so you'll have to re-write this using unnaturally clumsy code. Though I guess just replacing the `print` statements with `for line in (edges, middle, edges): print(line)` meets the problem as stated.

Comment: @Duncan: How does that meet the requirement of "using `for i in range(5)`"? I suppose you could do something really artificial, like `for i in range(5): print((edges+'\n', middle+'\n', edges+'\n', '', '')[i], end='')`, but that would be pretty silly…

Answer (score 0):

```
def printBoxes(n):
    top = "+--" * n + "+"
    middle = "|  " * n + "|"

    print(top)
    print(middle)
    print(top)

printBoxes(5)
```